# GitHub API rate limit does not exceed with Apache HttpClient

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, github-api

I make requests to GitHub API.

When I use this code, [rate limit](https://developer.github.com/v3/rate_limit/) decreases by one on every call.

```
new URL(url).openStream()
```

But when I use Apache HttpClient library, it does not.

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet();
httpGet.setURI(new URL(url).toURI());
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
```

How can that be possible?

Comment: Can you debug it? Comparing the HTTP requests may help you finding differences

Comment: @webo80 technically I can't, it works only on a remote linux machine, when I tried it on local windows machine, rate limit decreased as usual

Answer (score 0):

> How can that be possible?

From the API's side -- the rate limit will not be decreased for 304 responses:

https://developer.github.com/v3/#conditional-requests

So, if the HTTP library you're using is making conditional requests and those requests result in a 304, then the rate limit will not change.

Does that explain things perhaps?

Comment: I'm afraid it is not my case, requests urls are different and they do not use this header